# How to check by json file, if the input data are correct?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

How can I validate a user's input (Product_ID) in html by a json files which contains the arrays/information, while using node.js?
If the Product_ID (in Json File) doesn't exist/is not correct, it should alert an error message.

For example:

data.json

```
[
  {  
    "Product_ID": "887",
    "Name": "Name1",
  },
  {
    "Product_ID": "888",
    "Name": "Name2",
  }
]
```

product.html

```
<form id="product" action='/information.json' method="POST">
  <label class="product_ID">
    <input id="value" name="Proudct_ID" type="text" required/>
    <span class="placeholder">Enter product ID </span>
  </label>
</form>
```

information.js

```
app.post('/information', (req, res) => {
  $.get.JSON('information.json', function(data) {
    document.write(data.Product_ID);
});
```

I don't know exactly, how I can write the function in information.json, so that the Product_Id will be checked in the information.json file and display an (error) message.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You mean `information.js`

Comment: It's `$.getJSON`, however that's jQuery, i.e. client-side code. In node you simply do `const data = require('data.json');`; now you have to add `name="product_id"` to your <input> and `action="/information" method="post"` to your <form>, and you can check `req.body.product_id` against `data`.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG! I edited the html file. But am still not sure about the information.js file. So I do not need `app.post('/information', (req..... ` ? I just write `const data = require ('data.json') `  to check weather the data ar in the json file or not? And on which place to I need to do the display/alert part? It would be so great, if you could give me some tips.

Comment: You absolutely need the `app.post(...)` part to handle the form submission. Loading the JSON file is mostly independent of that, but needs to happen before so the data is available when your node code handles the form data. However, while I'd love to help, you seem to be lacking basic express knowledge? If so, helping you amounts to teaching you how express and POST requests work, which is way beyond the scope of an SO question.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG .You are right, am not an expert yet and am not expecting any teaching lesson :)  I was just a bit confused....  Am just focusing on solving my main question, how I can validate the input in html by the json file.

Comment: Here's a working minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-browser-52in4?file=/src/index.js The main mechanism is in lines 4, 16, and 19

Comment: oh that's so great of you @ChrisG ! Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. Finally,  I realized my error in reasoning. I have just one short question:why do you use `action="/information"` if you don't have any information file (at least I didn't see one) ?

Comment: The `action` part of a form is the URL that gets requested from the server when the form is submitted. I use `app.post("/information", ...)` on the backend to handle the form. It's a URL, and has no direct relation to a filename. Again, your node code is dealing with two completely separate mechanisms here: 1) handling a form submission 2) reading data from the hard drive for further use.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChrisG. I got it now :)))

Comment: hey @ChrisG sorry, I need to ask you something again about `app.post("/information",..)` I have researched a lot and I understand, what's the purpose of "/information" but I always get the error: "Firefox can't find the file at '/information" (don't know why it is searching for a file). I used your code on my local device, I tried different things but I don't get what's the problem... as I read the routing should be ok (as it also works in your codesandbox). I really feel guilty to ask you again, but do you have any suggestion what could be wrong, due to my error? - Thank you very much.

Comment: When / how *exactly* are you getting that Firefox error message? Are you clicking a link? What does it say in the address bar?

Comment: @ChrisG first I run the server (node index.js) in the terminal. than I open the html file, here it looks like yours. Afterwards I enter a product ID and click "submit query" and this the error "Firefox can't find the file at /information" appears. In the address bar it says: "file:///information"

Comment: That's what I thought; you're not supposed to just double-click the html file; you need to visit your express server's output: go to http://localhost:3000 instead (if your server uses a different port, use that; my codesandbox for instance uses 8080)

Comment: ahhh okay. Thank you @ChrisG ... I get an other error now "The page isn’t redirecting properly" but I will check for this and than I guess it should work well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think there might be an issue in `information.js`

```js
app.post('/information', (req, res) => {
  $.get.JSON('information.json', function(data) {
    document.write(data.Product_ID);
  }); // closing $.get.JSON function (I think you missed this one)
}); // closing app.post function
```

Other then that I recommend looking in to [Joi validation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0).
It has an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) if you are using NPM.
If not you can always download it from the [GitHub](https://github.com/sideway/joi/releases)

Comment: Thank you @TessavWalstijn . I never heard of Joi validation. Do you think it makes more sense in my case? I was planing to go with node js / jquery...

Comment: There is a jquery plugin for validation (Found it by googling "jquery validation"). I don't know how your project is set up and I don't want to say what is better (things can be achieved by different routes). I want to make sure that you know that jquery is becoming obsolete in javascript framework ecosystem. It is recommended to use vanilla javascript or any MVC framework.

NOTE: This does not mean that you should not use jquery you are free to use the tools you want.